# inserting a single unclosed tag into element, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to insert an unclosed tag into a selector:

```
$("div.crop-to-select").html("")
$("div.crop-to-select").append("<table>")
```

where I want to do the closing  later, myself:

```
$("div.crop-to-select").append("</table>")
```

I am finding, though, that the append always adds

```
<table></table>
```

each time. My table is getting closed before I can put any data into it.
Is there a different jQuery function for this?

Comment: jQuery manipulates the *DOM*. The DOM contains objects, there's no concept of an object being "closed" or "unclosed". So, you're appending a `table` object to the DOM. You would then work to manipulate the contents of that table, perhaps as [insomniac's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14394815/15498) suggests.

Comment: Thanks, @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Yes, I need to think through how to add rows and entries to the table, to the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
$("div.crop-to-select").append("<table>"); // This is fine..
$("div.crop-to-select table").html("-----ADD YOUR DATA HERE ------"); // But data which 
you want to put inside table can be added here..
```

Comment: @insomniac, thanks. Appreciate the explanation, in tandem with another answer.